# Error de sintaxis, número inválido de argumentos en 'LIKE' y '||'

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql, sintaxis

Un error en la base de datos ha hecho que se reinicien todos los números de secuencia a 1 así que he decidido avanzar las secuencias automáticamente con un procedimiento de PL/SQL (no son demasiadas secuencias pero son suficientes como para que no sea práctico hacerlo a mano). No soy un experto en SQL y tengo algunos errores de sintaxis que no sé cómo solucionar, en concreto la comparación de cadenas y alguna otra cosa. Si pudierais comentarme por qué falla la línea `IF(seq_name LIKE 'SEQ_%') THEN` el gestor de BDD es Oracle.

El substring se realiza porque la secuencia se llama (una de dos) `SEQ_PrimaryKey` o `SEQPrimaryKey` (las pk tienen nombre único en teoría)

```
declare

    max_seq_val int(9);
    table_name   VARCHAR2(100);
    table_primary_key VARCHAR2(100);
 begin

   for seq_name in (SELECT sequence_name from dba_sequences WHERE sequence_owner = 'USER_NAME')
    LOOP

        --getting table id
        --if(REGEXP_LIKE(seq_name,'SEQ_%')) then
        IF(seq_name LIKE 'SEQ_%') THEN
            SELECT SUBSTR(seq_name, 4) INTO table_primary_key FROM dual;
        ELSE 
            SELECT SUBSTR(seq_name, 3) INTO table_primary_key FROM dual;
        END IF;

        --obtener tabla
        execute immediate 'SELECT cols.table_name
                            FROM all_cons_columns cols, all_constraints cons
                            WHERE cols.column_name = '''|| table_primary_key || '''
                            AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
                            AND cons.constraint_type = ''P''
                            AND cols.owner = ''USER_NAME'' and rownum = 1;'
            INTO table_name;

        --guardar máximo id de la tabla
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select max(' || table_primary_key || ') from ' || table_name ||';' INTO max_seq_val;

        --iterar en la secuencia          

        BEGIN
           FOR i IN 1..max_seq_val LOOP
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || seq_name || '.nextval FROM dual;';
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'commit;';
           END LOOP;
           COMMIT;
        END;

    end loop;
 end;
```

Los errores que obtengo son:

> LINEA "IF(seq_name LIKE 'SEQ_%') THEN"
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'LIKE'
>
> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || seq_name || '.nextval FROM dual;';
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

Comment: IF(seq_name.sequence_name  LIKE 'SEQ_%') THEN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He solucionado todos los problemas, con este código podemos calcular todos los números de secuencia del usuario siempre que estén ligados con el nombre del campo. Subo el código para que cualquiera que pueda necesitarlo lo utilice

```
declare

    max_seq_val INTEGER(10);

    table_name   VARCHAR2(100);
    table_primary_key VARCHAR2(100);

    query VARCHAR2(300);

 BEGIN


    --for en las secuencias
   for seq_name in (SELECT sequence_name from dba_sequences WHERE sequence_owner = 'ALBNET63')
    LOOP


        --getting table id
        table_primary_key := seq_name.sequence_name;

        --Se parsea el nombre de la primary key a partir de la secuencia
        IF(substr(seq_name.sequence_name,1,4)='SEQ_') THEN
            SELECT SUBSTR(seq_name.sequence_name, 5) INTO table_primary_key FROM dual;
        ELSE 
            SELECT SUBSTR(seq_name.sequence_name, 4) INTO table_primary_key FROM dual;
        END IF;          




        -- La query saca la tabla a partir de la primary key
        query := 'SELECT table_name FROM all_cons_columns WHERE column_name = ''' || table_primary_key ||''' AND owner = ''ALBNET63'' AND constraint_name not like ''%$%'' and rownum=1';

        execute immediate query iNTO table_name;






        --guardar máximo id de la tabla

        query := 'select max(' || table_primary_key || ') from ' || table_name;
        dbms_output.put_line(query);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query INTO max_seq_val;
            --Si esto está a null significa que esas tablas no tienen valores
        if(max_seq_val IS null) THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('la clave de '|| table_name || ' ES NULL');
        ELSE
                DECLARE 
                    CURRENTVAL INTEGER(10);
                BEGIN
                   dbms_output.put_line('la clave de '|| table_name || ' ES ' || seq_name.sequence_name);


                  --Bloque que devuelve las secuencias a donde siempre debieron estar
                    declare
                        CURRENT_SEQ   NUMBER;
                    BEGIN
                       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || seq_name.sequence_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO CURRENT_SEQ;

                       -- Added check for 0 to avoid "ORA-04002: INCREMENT must be a non-zero integer"
                       IF (max_seq_val - CURRENT_SEQ - 1) != 0
                       THEN
                          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter sequence ' || seq_name.sequence_name || ' increment by ' || (max_seq_val - CURRENT_SEQ - 1) || ' minvalue 0';
                       END IF;

                       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || seq_name.sequence_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO CURRENT_SEQ;

                       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter sequence ' || seq_name.sequence_name || ' increment by 1 ';

                       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Sequence ' || seq_name.sequence_name || ' is now at ' || max_seq_val);
                    END;

                   COMMIT;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || seq_name.sequence_name || '.nextval FROM dual' INTO CURRENTVAL;
                  dbms_output.put_line(CURRENTVAL);
                END;
        END IF;

    end loop;
 end;
```

Answer (score 1):

El comando LIKE es parte de lenguaje de SQL y no de Procedimientos almacenados, no puedes usar like en esta parte del código

```
IF(seq_name LIKE 'SEQ_%') THEN
-- comandos
END IF;
```

En su lugar puedes aplicar con SUBSTRING como lo hizo Kaostias

```
IF substr(seq_name.sequence_name,1,4)='SEQ_') THEN
-- comandos
END IF;
```